# Does every singular countable noun must be used with an article with it?

Tags: articles, zero-article

[Source](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/Types-of-Nouns.html)
There are categories of nouns like:proper nouns, common nouns, material nouns, compound nouns, countable nouns, uncountable(nouns) or mass nouns, collective nouns, concrete nouns, abstract nouns, pronouns.

I heard a sentence in a TV series as:

> You've also made clear your desire to replace me as **leader** of the Decepticons.

I wonder what kind of noun is the **leader** in this context and why it is not preceded by an article?

Another example from [The Hound of the Baskervilles](https://sherlock-holm.es/stories/pdf/a4/1-sided/houn.pdf)

> I never hurt man or woman in my life that I know of.

Would the following sentences be grammatically correct?

> I never hurt **a** man or **a** woman in my life that I know of.
>   (**a** could also be replaced by **any**).
>
> I never hurt men or women in my life that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that in the second example, man and woman are being used as collective nouns for humankind.

In the first example, it's not that "leader" is a separate kind of noun, but that its article is made clear by its context. You could certainly say "**the leader**" of the Decepticons, but by definition there is only one leader (at a time).  The article isn't necessary and can be elided.

Often, we see this elision in the construction "as [noun] of [some group]"
For example:

- "**As captain** of the cheerleading squad, Kelly is responsible for try-outs."
- "**As headmaster** of
  Hogwarts, Dumbledore knew everything that went on in the castle."
- "**As C.E.O.** of Apple, Steve Jobs encouraged innovation."

We see a similar non-article construction when we say someone has been "**elected President** of the U.S." or has "**become King**."

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, I believe it's used as a collective noun meaning all men and all women. Yes, you can also use "any".

Comment: Why not used with an article as I have shown?

Comment: I think because of the literary style he was using.